# Uploading Python third party libraries

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google App engine documentation states that it is possible to upload and use third party libraries provided they written in pure Python.

What are the steps I need to take to do this?

Comment: Just include them in your app engine project directory (or a subdirectory) and `import` them using the relative path. When you deploy to appengine, the subdirectory will be included in the push as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So say that I want to include a library named "tweetstream" i just copy its folder in the app folder (which contains the app.yaml file) and in the application code just say "import tweetsream". Is that all? And wouldn't I be required to make changes in the app.yaml file for using third-party apps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I did is created a file called fix_path.py in my root directory that looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import jinja2   
# path to lib direcotory
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
```

Then I created a lib directory, and drop the module in there.

For example, I use WTForms.   My file structure looks like this.

- lib

  - wtforms
- fix_path.py
- somefile.py

when I am ready to call it from my somefile script

```
import fix_path # has to be first.
import wtforms
```

[here](https://github.com/buslinks/myblog) is this example in my github source.  checkout fix_path.py for setup and views.py for usage.

Comment: I do not understand what's the purpose of "fix_path.py" file? Also if I created the "lib" directory in the application root folder (which contains "app.yaml", would i need to mention path to lib directory then?

Comment: the fix_path file just routes to the lib directory where I store all my libraries.  I don't make mention of the lib folder in my app.waml file.

Comment: Shouldn't this just be in the `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried the same with following steps.

1. created a directory(lib) with init file i.e `lib/__init__.py` in my project root.
2. created my module (`mymodule.py`), and defined a function i.e.

   ```
   def myfunc():
       return "mycustomfunction"
   ```
3. imported mymodule in my `main.py`

   ```
   from lib import mymodule
   ```

I could use the returned value from `myfunc()` and could pass that as a template value to my jinja2 template

Similarly, if we follow what @rjz also pointed out in the first answer, if the 3rd Party library is just a module then we can keep that in libs with an **init** file and it can be imported with an import statement ( point 3) . If the 3rd party library is a package then we can keep it in the project root and import it again with an import statement as this one in the `main.py`:

```
from thirdpartypackage import *
```