# Django on Google App Engine- How to import/use 3rd party libraries?

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-app-engine, leaflet, geojson

I'm a begginer in both Django and Google App Engine. 
Running Django 1.9 on GAE, I would like to use these '3rd party' tools in my project:

django-geojson: https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-geojson

and django-leaflet: https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet

My problem is: How to upload these tools to the GAE, together with the rest of my project files, so that they can be used there, by my app?

I've already looked for answers here and found this question: [How to use custom python libraries and apps in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324136/how-to-use-custom-python-libraries-and-apps-in-google-app-engine)
But I really don't understand what the person meant/what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include third party Python libraries in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libraries-in-google-app-engine) The next highly-voted answer is actually better than the accepted one - pointing to the officially recommended procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good guide on how to use Django on GAE here:
https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

When you follow that guide you get a requirements-vendor.txt file. Edit that file and add `django-geojson` and `django-leaflet` to it.
After that you can run `pip install -r requirements-vendor.txt -t lib/` to install them.

Now you can follow the rest of the guide for instructions on how to upload everything to GAE.