# Why am I not able to import markdown2 into my App Engine application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, markdown

I have built a blog which is being hosted on App Engine, and I want to implement markdown. I have installed he markdown2 module after looking it up on Github and I can use it in the terminal console.

But when I try to import the same module in my program, I hit an error which states that there is no such module. I even tried to use sys.path method but I still get the error.

The traceback for my error is :

```
File "/home/bigb/google_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 189, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/home/bigb/google_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 227, in _LoadHandler
handler = __import__(path[0])
File "/home/bigb/google_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bigb/google_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1859, in load_module
return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
File "/home/bigb/google_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bigb/google_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1723, in FindAndLoadModule
description)
File "/home/bigb/google_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bigb/google_projects/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1666, in LoadModuleRestricted
description)
File "/home/bigb/google_projects/my-ramblings/blog.py", line 12, in <module>
import markdown2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third-party libraries on your local computer are not automatically included on Google App Engine.

You have to add these libraries directly to your source code. These threads give a detailed explanation how to go about doing this:

1) [How do I manage third-party Python libraries with Google App Engine? (virtualenv? pip?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863557/how-do-i-manage-third-party-python-libraries-with-google-app-engine-virtualenv)

2) [Uploading Python third party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648256/uploading-python-third-party-libraries-with-google-app-engine)

3) [How to include third party Python libraries in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libs-in-google-appengine)

Comment: Really helpful, and I already know that I had to juggle around with sys to import 3rd party libraries into App Engine but I did not know how to do that. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste 'markdown' source code folder in your application folder. It will work.