# How do I upload multiple libraries which my app needs to Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dependencies, reddit

I wrote a script to control a reddit bot using praw, and decided I wanted to upload it to some website which would execute it automatically every ten or so minutes.

For that I chose Google App Engine (b/c it was free and google). Unfortunately I'm not sure how to upload its dependencies. After googling around I found out I had to place praw in the src directory of my app, which I did.

The app threw an error on running, saying that it could not find a module named requests- to fix that I just threw six in my src dir, which is the only dependency of praw. The next time it ran, the app engine log said the script could not find the module "pkg_resources."

To find this I just started up python and ran

```
import pkg_resources
print(pkg_resources)
```

which linked my to a .pyc which I placed into my app's src directory. Unfortunately the next time the script ran it failed again, saying it could not locate the module pkg_resources.

Because of this I have two questions:

One, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in trying to upload praw's dependencies to the app engine? and...

Two, while locating all the files I needed, I realized that trying to do upload all the dependencies of a package is a pain. Is there any utuility which would generate a list of folders that I would need to place in my src folder?

Answers are appreciated :)

Comment: Have you looked at existing answers on SO?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648256/uploading-python-third-party-libraries-with-google-app-engine