# How to use AES with GAE python?

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, python-2.7, pycrypto

I would like to encrypt the data transferred between GAE app and my android application (*https* will not help since the key should be dynamic). I am thinking about AES (128-bit) encryption.

I've tried to use `pycrypto` (GAE SDK 1.8.6, python 2.7, OS X 10.9):

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

But when I `import Crypto` it can not find the module:

```
ImportError: No module named Crypto
```

Is there any other built-in module I can use? Or, is there any way to be able to use `pycrypto` (should I install it manually)?

Comment: I had a similar problem, here is how I solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350204/app-engine-importerror-no-module-named-crypto-hash/29354265#29354265

Answer (score 1):

This happens to be an App Engine supplied module, as detailed here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

> The Python 2.7 runtime includes some third-party modules. Some of
>   these are available by default; others are only available if
>   configured. You can specify which version you want to use.
>   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#Configuring_Libraries

To enable included libraries edit your app.yaml like this:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
```

In general you'd need to add the files themselves to the same directory that app.yaml is in, as per this question: [Uploading Python third party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648256/uploading-python-third-party-libraries-with-google-app-engine) but this happens to be a supplied library.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I replaced version `2.6` with `latest` (what you recommend), but it didn't help - still Crypto is not found.

Comment: I can get "from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA" to work on the playground.  Have a look. https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/playground/p/6423617780842496/#main.py

Comment: hmm, further to that last comment it throws no error even without that line in the app.yaml. dunno for now.

Comment: are you experiencing error in server or localhost? in localhost you need to install pycrypto manually, in appengine server you only need to specify it in the yaml file

Comment: lol, yes, there should be a new tag I think for the local dev_server related questions. This is no doubt it.

Comment: @marcadian, yes, I am talking about dev_server (i.e. localhost).

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used easy_install to install pycrypto, it's not working (old gae version though) so I did this:
- download [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) 
- extract, cd to the pycrypto folder
- python setup.py build
- sudo python setup.py install