# Will Robohash run as a python app at App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We have a need for Robohashes that never change and are very secure and reliable.  This is perfect for a Google app where it can be monitored, run over SSL and be extremely reliable.

I really don't have much python experience.  Would someone please give a mile-high view?  Would it be easy to host Robohash as a python app at the App Engine?

`requirements.txt
pillow <- not supported
tornado <- looks like it will work`

Are there other challenges, like say how files are accessed?  Java in the appengine couldn't not read the file system last I checked it had to use resources.  Do you think it will be worth-while for me to pursue?

This is the version we need: https://github.com/BitShares/Robohash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that won't work directly as an application deployed to the standard [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine) (GAE) runtime.

There is a way to [add third party modules to your GAE app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703151/how-to-use-a-different-version-of-pycrypto-in-gae-python), and it would probably work with pillow, but not with Tornado as it would collide with the webapp2 web framework used by GAE.

Having said that, there are good news for you.

You could use [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) that are in the middle of deploying only your application and of having your own virtual instance where you install everything.

With managed VMs you could build your [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes) with exactly what you need.